# Inline display of divs with child overlapped divs

Tags: html, css

I'm a noob, trying everyday to learn more about CSS (even though I'm clumsy and "not a natural", my brain steams out like an old computer). I want to find out how to code a set of independent modules which share the same style and are displayed inline in two rows of two columns. I want to recreate a paper stack for each module, using `z-index` and `absolute` positioning for it.

I made this image to show what I'm looking for:

[image]

I tried `display:inline` for the top div - but this way, I had to code individual overlapped divs for each module, using `position:absolute` and coordinates. What would be most desirable is that a single module+overlap could be repeated, using the same class (without having to change each module's overlapped div coordinates).

Does anyone have an idea about how to do this using CSS? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could do the following. You'll want to resize to whichever dimensions serve you best. JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/CNPJ9/2/

```
<div class="contain">
    <div class="box">
         <h1>A</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="behind"></div>
</div>
<div class="contain">
    <div class="box">
         <h1>B</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="behind"></div>
</div>
<div class="contain">
    <div class="box">
         <h1>C</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="behind"></div>
</div>
<div class="contain">
    <div class="box">
         <h1>D</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="behind"></div>
</div>

.contain {
    margin:25px 25px;
    float:left;
}
.box h1 {
    font: 8em normal Futura, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    color:#f1f1f1;
}
.box {
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    background:#000;
    z-index:1;
    float:left;
    position:absbolute;
}
.behind {
    width:350px;
    height:325px;
    margin-left:25px;
    background:#333;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: Just a little question @Blake, if you don't mind... How could I align the whole set of modules to the center of the document?

Comment: margin:auto to your parent element that contains these divs.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help you.
[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vishalkin/3rVxA/)

```
.abc{
    width=300px;
    height:200px;
    margin:50px;
    border:solid 2px black;   
    border-bottom: 5px double blue;
}
```

Comment: I need a div that is overlapped by the big div on top (A,B,C and D).